# How to set up static IP and default gateway on a ZTE T3000?

Tags: router, setup

I need help with this section of the setup, it asks me for:

1. **IP Address**: 192.168.0.1
2. **Subnet mask**: 255.255.255.0
3. **Default gateway**: ??????????? (What must I place here?) If I use the IP from above it shows me that it cannot be the same.)
4. **Primary DNS**: 192.168.0.107   - PiHole
5. **Secondary DNS**: 1.1.1.1

This is the only way that I can change my DNS on the router. But this is keeping me from doing that.

**Note**: My router/internet setup is: ZTE MC889 outdoor/indoor unit with my 5G SIM card, that is connected to my ZTE T3000 WiFi router. Above are the WiFi router settings that I want to change.

ZTE T3000 connection settings:

[image]

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio No, this is the WAN setting, not the LAN one. The WAN IP should be either a public IP or CGNAT IP if the WAN is connected to the ISP, in which case the gateway should be another public / CGNAT IP and it's likely impossible to use static IP at all. If the WAN is connected to another home router (including those modem router that is not in bridge mode), the gateway here should the LAN IP of that "outer" router and the IP here should be one within the LAN subnet of that "outer" router.

Comment: You should see if the router allows you to fiddle the DNS server its DHCP server advertise. It's more ideal to change that instead of setting the pihole as the upstream DNS server in the router's WAN setting (if that could even work at all).

Comment: @TomYan Understood.

Comment: Actually @ReddyLutonadio was right on that the gateway here should the LAN IP of `mc889`. It's just that it's likely neither the IP/gateway needed here would be any 192.168.0.x, judging by the pihole's IP, *unless the pihole is not connected to the `t3000` but the `mc889`* (in which case the gateway needed here is likely `192.168.0.1` whereas the IP needed is some other `192.168.0.x`). It's probably easier for you to switch back the DHCP temporarily, and copy the WAN properties shown in some info/troubleshooting page for the static configuration.

Comment: Thank you so so much, its working perfectly now,